# CORS not working in Firefox

Tags: php, ajax, apache, firefox, cors

I am trying to load data into a jQuery dialog via ajax but the request is failing in Firefox (34.0.5).  Works fine and I get no complaints in Chrome and Safari.

My apache conf contains:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

The jQuery is simply:

```
$('#dialog').load('example.php', function() { $('#dialog').dialog('open'); });
```

Firefox responds with the following console error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.example.com/example.php. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Inspecting the response headers from the ajax request they all seem to be intact and inline with what's declared in apache.  Should I be including some other directive or changing the configuration in some way for this to work?

UPDATE: At the root of the issue is the fact that I'd like both `example.com` and `www.example.com` to function the same.  The site in question always has a tag in the header `<base href="www.example.com" />` in both instances as this is part of the default site framework.  I've since discovered that removing this link allows the ajax request to work on example.com, even when it still specifically calls a resource from the www subdomain.

Interestingly, many aspects of the request and response headers change when this tag is removed.  For anyone who might have a clue about the implications here I'm pasting both the request and response headers below.

Here are the headers with `<base>` tag removed.  In this case the ajax call was successful:

*RESPONSE*

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sun, 18 Jan 2015 22:11:04 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxx; path=/; HttpOnly
    language=en; expires=Tue, 17-Feb-2015 22:11:04 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=www.example.com
    currency=CAD; expires=Tue, 17-Feb-2015 22:11:04 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=www.example.com
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public
    Pragma: no-cache
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    access-control-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
    access-control-allow-origin: *
    access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
    Content-Length: 1515
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

*REQUEST*

```
    GET /example.php HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.example.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
    Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://example.com/
    Origin: http://example.com
    x-insight: activate
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

And here are the headers with the `<base>` tag intact.  These headers reflect the scenario where the ajax call failed.  It's worth noting that the 'Location' field in the response header says 'https' even though this was not happening over an https connection:

*RESPONSE*

```
    HTTP/1.1 302 Found
    Date: Sun, 18 Jan 2015 22:12:26 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5
    Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxx; path=/; HttpOnly
    language=en; expires=Tue, 17-Feb-2015 22:12:26 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=www.example.com
    currency=CAD; expires=Tue, 17-Feb-2015 22:12:26 GMT; Max-Age=2592000; path=/; domain=www.example.com
    Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public
    Pragma: no-cache
    Status: 302
    Location: https://www.example.com/index.php
    access-control-allow-methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
    access-control-allow-origin: *
    access-control-allow-headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
    Content-Length: 0
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/html
```

*REQUEST*

```
    OPTIONS /example.php HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.example.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0 FirePHP/0.7.4
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Origin: http://example.com
    Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
    Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
    x-insight: activate
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Comment: Are the CORS headers being sent twice? I had a recent problem where I had mistakenly added it to my htaccess as well as my apache conf. This caused the header values to be sent twice which caused some browsers to not work properly.

Comment: Not that I can see.  I don't have anything set in .htaccess only apache vhost conf - though think it also might happen if you use `Header add` instead of `Header set`.  As it stands I am only seeing them once in the response headers.

Comment: I'm having similar issue (that's works on Chrome, not in FF) but without <base> tag being used.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin), you can't use the wildcard for "credentialed requests", so maybe your request falls in that category.